# how can I make the values from the array be used in the loop in order?

Tags: python, arrays

In my array, for example, there are 3 values. Arrays are used in code that repeats 3 times, but it is inconvenient to edit.

```
words = ["chair", "carrot", "sea"]
print ("The first word is", words[0])
print ("The second word is", words[1])
print ("The third word is", words[2])
```

simple example of the code

Comment: Do you actually need to print first/second/third in the message?

Comment: maybe better find some tutorial because this is basic knowledge how to use `for`-loop.

Comment: if you really need to use words `"first", "second", "third"` then you may use second list and `zip(list1, words)` to group them.

Comment: @JohnGordon maybe it's doesn't matter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
words = ["chair", "carrot", "sea"]

for i in range(len(words)):
    print("The", ["first", "second", "third"][i], "word is", words[i])
```

Try this code

Comment: I would assign `["first", "second", "third"]` to variable (ie, `numbers`) - to make code more readable. And then I would use `zip(numbers, words)` instead of `range(len())`. And if you would describe what you do then you wouldn't get downvote.